# How to get child nodes with ELEMENT_NODE type only

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm parsing a xml document using java DOM and I need to get every single node for doing something.

I have this code:

```
public void analyze_file(Node node){
        if(node.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE){
            //do something
        }
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
        for(int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++){
            if(list.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                analyze_file(list.item(i));
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is that, my xml file is very large *( > 30000 lines)*, and the code above needs too much time for checking whether a node is of `ELEMENT_NODE` type or not. I see that if the program stopped after it reached the last `ELEMENT_NODE` node, the execution time would be very small.

Is there any way to get all child nodes whose type is `ELEMENT_NODE` only?

For example: `NodeList list = node.getElementChildNodes();`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
node.getElementsByTagName("*")
```

From JavaDoc: Returns a NodeList of all descendant Elements with a given tag name, in document order. Name - The name of the tag to match on. The special value "*" matches all tags.

Comment: Note, the `getElementsByTagName("*")` method only works on `Element`s. You would have to cast `node` as an `Element` before you can use the method.